# Modified CDATA String

Tags: android, string-formatting, cdata

I have a string as below:

```
<string name="ramadan_fasting_completion"><![CDATA[
You have made up all # days of fasting missed during Ramadan due to your period.
<br/><br/> If you enjoyed this experience, we\'d really appreciate it if you took a moment to
<font color=#5FCA1C>rate and review App</font> on the Play Store.
<br/><br/> Otherwise see you in Ramdan ?!]]></string>
```

It works perfectly fine when I set text to textview in below way:

```
String congratulatoryDescription = getString(R.string.ramadan_fasting_completion);
setHtmlText(txtInformationDescription,congratulatoryDescription);
```

However, if I modify the string with following lines and then set it in textview
"rate and review App" text is not colored.

```
congratulatoryDescription = congratulatoryDescription.replace("#",totalDays);
congratulatoryDescription = congratulatoryDescription.replace("?",nextYear);
```

is proper but font is not.

Currently, I have a workaround with spannable string but I am not satisfied with that. Can you please guide how to user the static CDATA and deal with string replacement.

P.S: I know I could have used string formatter like %1s but since I have an Arabic version for the same I could not use formatter properly.

Comment: Probably you also replace # in color

Comment: Why Downvote? Please explain

Comment: @DeniErdyneev yup, you were right. My Bad!!